# Paypal REST API returning 404 Not Found only in live mode

Tags: api, paypal, http-status-code-404, paypal-subscriptions

Having a weird problem with Paypal API. I'm using the Subscriptions API an before creating a subscription, I need to create a plan. In the Sandbox enviroment, the resource `/billing/plans` (https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans) works fine, but in Live mode (https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans) I get ´404 Not Found´ with an empty body. Didn't found any hint at the docs. Any ideas?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Merchant Technical Support (https://www.paypal-support.com/s/?language=en_US), they made a correction and now it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of easy mistakes you could have made which I made which give rise to 'the blank screen'.  A very easy one: Check that your country codes comply with the iso standards. I was using UK instead of GB. Particularly your shipping address. You can replicate this error by putting in the wrong country code.

Also ensure that your start_date is greater than the current date. The test samples contain old start dates which are behind current dates. Increment the date function with 36000 instead of 3600 to ensure that your start date is greater than an extra hour from your current date or just hardcode a very late date.  Your server might be operating at a different timezone.

The token passed was not found in the system....If you have a blank screen it is likely that the access token is not being passed after the 'first run' because you do not have an approval link as a result of the pre-passing error. It sounds like it could be a basic content error but you have likely checked for this.

Check the runtime log file and look out for the approval link. A successful 201 pass will give you something like the following.

```
"links":
    [
        {
            "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-22608875RF361971P",
            "rel":"approval_url",
            "method":"REDIRECT"
        },{
            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-22608875RF361971P/agreement-execute",
            "rel":"execute",
            "method":"POST"
        }
    ]
```

These are some of the errors that I have encountered which might be of use to you perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal's customer service is very poor. We will not get any answer from them.
Temporary, we can use backend to create via https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans/plan/create

Comment: How does this route work? Is it a POST? Is there a documentation about it?